# referencing mupdf in Qt4 project

Tags: c++, compilation, qt4, mupdf

I have libfitz.a and libmupdf.a in /usr/local/lib (previously compiled).
then I included the headers:

```
#include <fitz.h>
#include <mupdf.h>
```

then I put:

```
INCLUDEPATH  +=/home/pc/sviluppo/mupdf-0.9
INCLUDEPATH  +=/home/pc/sviluppo/mupdf-0.9/fitz
INCLUDEPATH  +=/home/pc/sviluppo/mupdf-0.9/pdf

LIBS         += -L/usr/local/lib -lfitz
LIBS         += -L/usr/local/lib -lmupdf
```

in .pro file, but my program just reaches to types in the headers, not the library. The error is

```
/.../mainwindow.cpp:-1: error: undefined reference to `pdf_open_xref(pdf_xref_s**, char const*, char*)'
```

What's wrong?

Comment: How and/or for which architecture (32bit/64bit) did you install Qt and mupdf ?

Comment: I have 32bit system, I succesfully compiled mupdf because tools are available; I successfully used poppler in Qt-4; what's wrong now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a C library, and they didn't use `extern "C"` to allow the headers to be included easily in C++. 
So you have to do it yourself:

```
extern "C" {
    #include <fitz.h>
    #include <mupdf.h>
}
```

According to mupdf MakeFile, you should put the libraries in that order in your .pro (the more dependent static library should be placed before its dependencies):

```
LIBS         += -L/usr/local/lib -lmupdf -lfitz
LIBS         += -lfreetype -ljbig2dec -ljpeg -lopenjpeg -lz -lm
```

Comment: thx @alexisdm now it seems that qt-creator is trying to compile all mupdf so many errors are issued (>1000). For example the first error is /usr/local/lib/libmupdf.a(pdf_page.o):-1: In function `pdf_find_page_number': It also seems that it encounters errors when reading from usr/local/lib libraries like libmupdf.a then others errors like /home/pc/sviluppo/mupdf-0.9/pdf/pdf_page.c:36: error: undefined reference to `fz_dict_gets'

Comment: @P5music These are linker errors, try what I added to the answer.